# Easiest way to front Weblogic 9.2 with apache 2.x

Tags: windows, apache, proxy, weblogic

I want to put Apache 2.2.9 in front of a Weblogic 9.2 server on Windows XP. What does it take to do that ?

I probably need mod_proxy on the apache side ?

As far as Weblogic and apache are concerned, is there something similar to mod_jk ?

I would like this setup so that I can introduce some filtering later on. But for now, the goal is to allow other computers to access weblogic appserver so that Apache forwards all requests coming to it (at a certain URL) to Weblogic.

I have done this several times earlier BUT have forgotten how I did it.

Thanks for any pointers,

---

I guess http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs81/plugins/apache.html answers most of the basic fundas. Will update the forum if I have more inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this is to use the *Apache HTTP Server plug-in* provided by BEA/Oracle and bundled with Weblogic.

For details, refer to the legacy [BEA WebLogic Server 9.2 Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/index.html) and more precisely to:

- [Installing and Configuring the Apache HTTP Server Plug-In](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/plugins/apache.html)
- [Parameters for Web Server Plug-Ins](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/plugins/plugin_params.html)

**Note**: These links are the up to date links since http://edocs.bea.com/ is now down.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Pascal about the weblogic plugin --that is the preffred one, I can still list two choices for you

***1> Apache Plugin for weblogic:***

this not only forwards request to weblogic from Apache, but can also act as HTTP load balancer for your weblogic setup.

```
update httpd.conf to load weblogic_module   --> mod_wl_20.so

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>  
  WebLogicCluster w1s1.com:7001,w1s2.com:7001,w1s3.com:7001
  MatchExpression *.jsp  
  MatchExpression *.xyz
</IfModule>
```

***2> Apache Proxy pass***

if you are looking for simple redirect from Apache use this

```
update httpd.conf to load proxy_module --> mod_proxy.so

<Location /service>
 ProxyPass         http://wls1.com:7001/service
 ProxyPassReverse  http://wls1.com:7001/service
</Location>
```

use which ever suit your need

Answer (score 0):

We used the WebLogic plugin to load balance and front our applicatiosn, using virtual hosts and locations.

For example:

ServerName www.domain.com

WebLogicCluster 10.20.30.41:7002,10.20.30.42:7002
    SetHandler weblogic-handler

This config will balance requests to http://www.domain.com/PathToApplication
to 10.20.30.41:7002 and 10.20.30.42:7002.